# Word and etymology for "small of one's back"

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I've encountered the phrase *small of one's back* often when I was reading the Divergent series, and recently encountered it again on a Wikipedia article. I've searched its meaning on the internet, but I'm still confused as to where exactly it is located in the body. Some says it's near the buttocks , some says it's higher up, on the part where the usual "curve" is on the torso area. Where did the term came from? Where is it exactly? Is there a single word for it?

Comment: ***The small of the back*** is [the part of a person’s back where the spine curves in at the level of the waist.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/the-small-of-the-back) But I have no idea *why* it's called that.

Comment: Maybe it's called that because it's where the circumference of the torso is smallest? Or if you look at a profile, it's where the width is smallest. Both of these don't apply to obese people, though, so it's a pretty anachronistic term now.

Comment: @Barmar well I am obese. LOL

Comment: @BrianHitchcock it's actually my initials, so yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The small of the back* refers to **the narrow part of the back at the waist**, and derives from the original meaning of *small* as meaning narrow or (to quote the OED) "of no great extent laterally in comparison to length".

The word *small* is cognate with Old Frisian *smel* and Old Dutch *smal*; the predominant sense in these old Germanic words is slender or narrow, rather than diminutive in size. For instance in Chaucer's *Miller's Tale*: "Fair was this yonge wyf, and ther with al As eny wesele hir body gent and smal" ("her body elegant and slender as any weasel").

The OED gives as one meaning of *small* as a noun: "Usually with *the*. The small, slender, or narrow part of something." The first citation is from c. 1450 referring to "the smale off the legge" (*the small of the leg*); it also has "a smal of a pelyr" (*small of a pillar*) c. 1500. "Small of the back" has a tentative citation dated to 1536 (from a quotation in Thomas Wright, *Three Chapters Letters Suppression Monasteries*, 1843: "I am in a fayntt werynesse over all my body, butt cheffly in the small of my backe"), and more certain in 1575 ("If your Hawke chaunce to die, rippe hir and you shall finde a knubbe of the bignesse of a small Beane full vpon the reynes and the small of hir backe").

There is however considerable overlap in meaning between narrow and little. While *small* originally meant narrow, by the time it was used to refer to the small of the back, it had taken on more general usage for anything of small size. As well as the adjective, there were older, largely obsolete, meanings of *small* as a noun referring to a small person or thing, found in the 14th century. For instance c. 1303 "Many smale makeþ a grete" (*Many small makes a great*).

Hence the small of the back was originally the slender or narrow part. The OED defines **small of the back** under **small** as "the part of the back where the spine curves in at the level of the waist". It notes alternatives *the small of the waist*, and (now obsolete) *the small of the belly*.

"[small, adj. and n.2](https://www-oed-com.nls.idm.oclc.org/view/Entry/182404?rskey=5PCFkx&result=2&isAdvanced=false)". OED Online. March 2023. Oxford University Press. (accessed March 20, 2023).